# Wordpress Function Enqueue - Não consigo adicionar Jquery no tema

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Estou tentando adicionar o jquery no tema, todos css e js que coloco nas function são adicionados no codigo normalmente, mas o jquery que esta no diretório do meu tema não esta sendo adicionado. O arquivo existe na mesma pasta do `/js/bootstrap.min.js`

```
function enqueue_jquery() {
     // retira o jquery padrão do wordpress, ok retirou
     wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 

    // Não esta adicionando este jquery, que é o que preciso, no código
wp_enqueue_script(
    'jquery',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js',
    array(), // don't make jquery dependent on jquery...!
    '1.11.1',
    true
);

} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery');

function enqueue_styles_scripts() {

    //OK adicionou normal
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'style-theme',
        get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array('bootstrap-css')
    );

    //OK adicionou normal
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'bootstrap-css',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    );

    //OK adicionou normal
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'stylish-portfolio',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/othercss.css'
    );

    //OK adicionou normal
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'font-awesome',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css'

    ); 


    //Adicionou normal, mas como depende do jquery não esta funcionando
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bootstrap-js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',null
    );


} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles_scripts');


//ok adicionou normal 
function wpse_ie_conditional_scripts() { ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_ie_conditional_scripts' );

?>
```

No console apenas aparece o erro que o bootstrap.min.js depende do jquery para funcionar.

Agradeço ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque depois de usar o `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` se faz necessário 'registrá-lo' novamente antes de botá-lo novamente na fila. [Vide documentação](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/#comment-1836).

Logo, você poderia fazer algo do tipo:

```
function enqueue_jquery() {
    // retira o jquery padrão do wordpress
    wp_deregister_script('jquery' ); 

    // registra o novo jquery
    wp_register_script( 
         'jquery', 
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js',
         array(), 
         '1.11.1', 
         true
    );

    // enfileira o novo jquery registrado 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery');
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, já tinha conseguido resolver com o seguinte codigo diretamente, sem usar function `wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', false, '1.11.1');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`. Sua explicação me deu uma base de compreensão, saberia me dizer qual o efeito de registrar o jquery fora ou dentro de uma function?

Comment: Quando você fala fora, seria colocar o código que você citou acima, sem ser dentro de uma função no `functions.php` ou direto no template?

Comment: isso sem ser dentro de uma função, e no arquivo function.php

Comment: O que acontece é o seguinte: Quando se usa uma `function` aliada ao `add_action()` ou `add_filter()`, como lá em cima, estamos dizendo que a função `enqueue_jquery` vai executada com o hook `wp_enqueue_scripts`, por exemplo. É comum ver direto no código, chamadas de configuração direta do tema em si. Mas sendo sincero, não sei em que momento (e as consequências positivas ou negativas) os enfileiramentos iriam acontecer sem o uso do hook. Chutaria que o código adicionado seria executado na action `init` do tema.

Comment: Faz sentido, obrigada pela contribuição. Postei mais uma duvida [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178021/quais-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-wordpress-usar-para-controlar-o-tema-pelo-admin), se puder me ajudar novamente agradeço